# Cognito Custom message trigger to redirect to referer URL

Tags: java, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I work on a project with sites from multiples domain using the same Cognito user pool. I have a custom message trigger configured for the verification and forgot password emails and I need to put on the message body a link that redirects the user to the domain which the request was sent. Is there a way to get the referer for request?

Comment: There's a `website` user attribute that you could set.  I use that to indicate to the custom message trigger how to properly format the verification link.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. The custom message lambda trigger get these kind of information using the event object and the event object, as per [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#aws-lambda-triggers-custom-message-example) docs & my testing is something like this:

```
{
    "version": "1",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "userPoolId": "us-east-1_xxxxxxxx",
    "userName": "myuser",
    "callerContext": {
        "awsSdkVersion": "aws-sdk-unknown-unknown",
        "clientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "triggerSource": "CustomMessage_ForgotPassword",
    "request": {
        "userAttributes": {
            "sub": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-ad88-da626e7b6496",
            "email_verified": "true",
            "cognito:user_status": "CONFIRMED",
            "nickname": "nick",
            "name": "myname",
            "email": "email@example.com"
        },
        "codeParameter": "{####}",
        "usernameParameter": null
    },
    "response": {
        "smsMessage": null,
        "emailMessage": null,
        "emailSubject": null
    }
}
```

The only (slightly) relevant info is callerContext but its value would depend on what method is used to call the ForgotPassword API. Try testing this & log the event object in your SignUp lambda & see if you get some info (I don't think u can).

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head why not add a claim that indicates which domain the request has come from.

Or create one client in cognito per domain.

.. i prefer the claim approach, feels like it would be a useful claim to have further down the line.

Answer (score 0):

On forgot password request, get the referer from `APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent`'s headers: there's a header `referer`. And while creating `ForgotPasswordRequest`, set this referer into `clientMetadata`:

```
public void resetPassword(String email, String referer) {
    var forgotPasswordRequest = ForgotPasswordRequest.builder()
            .username(email)
            .clientId(COGNITO_USERS_POOL_APP_CLIENT_ID)
            .secretHash(calculateSecretHash(email))
            .clientMetadata(Map.of("referer", referer))
            .build();
    cognitoIdentityProviderClient.forgotPassword(forgotPasswordRequest);
}
```

Then in your trigger handler, just retrieve this referer:

```
  public Object handleRequest(Object event, Context context) {
      JsonObject json = gson.toJsonTree(event).getAsJsonObject();
      if ("CustomMessage_ForgotPassword".equals(json.get("triggerSource").getAsString())) {
        var request = json.get("request").getAsJsonObject();
        var clientMetadata = request.get("clientMetadata").getAsJsonObject();
        var referer = clientMetadata.get("referer").getAsString();
        
        // retrieve "codeParameter" and "email"
        // create message
        // set response "emailMessage", "emailSubject" and "smsMessage"  

        event = gson.fromJson(json, LinkedHashMap.class);
    }
    return event;
}
```